# How can i have this output in order to create a word2vec model using keras and numpy in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, word2vec

Hello I'm having a hard time trying to understand this, here's the deal, I'm trying to have the same output as the person who gave me the project, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong in the process, here's the given output [The output i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEfW.png)
and the output i have : [The output i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5TSP.png)

Here's what my code looks like :

```
#the keras model/graph would look something like this:
from keras import layers, optimizers, Model

 # embedding , 
embedding = layers.Embedding(Vt, vector_dim, input_length=1, name='embedding')
# entrée deux entier (couple de morceaux)
input_target = Input((1,), dtype='int32')
input_context = Input((1,), dtype='int32')

print(input_target)
print(input_context)

target = embedding(input_target)
context = embedding(input_context)

#target = layers.Reshape((vector_dim,))(target)
#context = layers.Reshape((vector_dim,))(context)

print("----------")
print(target)
print(context)

dot_product = layers.dot([target, context], axes=1)
dot_product = Flatten()(dot_product)
print(dot_product)
#dot_product = layers.Reshape((1,))(dot_product)
#dot_product = layers.Reshape((vector_dim,))(dot_product)

output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name="classif")(dot_product)

# # definition du modèle
Track2Vec = Model(inputs=[input_target, input_context], outputs=output)
Track2Vec.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Thanks in advance for trying to figure what is wrong in my work!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the layers.dot where you need to perform the dot product to give you (1,1) rather than (30,30).

Try to exchange you inputs for that layer.

'''
dot_product = layers.dot([context, target], axes=1)
'''
This should work.

Comment: Hello,  first of all thanks for your answer, sadly i have tried this but it seems like i always get the same results...

Comment: Yes it might be the case since in the layers.Reshape, they have the same shape.

Try to change one of the reshape to have it as (30,1) and another as (1,30) and then try with the initial code and then the exchange.

#target = layers.Reshape((vector_dim,1))(target)
#context = layers.Reshape((1,vector_dim))(context)

Let me know afterwards.

Comment: thanks Mohamad for your answer everything is working so fine, i just have one problem, the output that i want don't have two lines of reshape layers, so how can i remove them please in the next post

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, if you can elaborate since your output is a single value.

 If the answer was useful, please upvote it (or the comment).

Answer (score 0):

this is the output (i want to suppress the two reshape layers lines)  [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGHB1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`dot_product = Dot(axes=1)([target, context])`

you should also import :

`from keras.layers.merge import Dot`